# Higher than needed transaction fees

Tags: transaction, blockchain, fee

Let's say I have a transaction that I manually altered to include transaction fees that are higher than the required amount of fees. The transaction is perfectly balanced and, apart from this, does not differ from a normal transaction. Is this transaction valid ? Or will it be refused by the blockchain nodes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as the all inputs match the outputs (minus the fee), and the fee is *equal to or greater than* the minimum fee as per the protocol parameters, it should be a valid transaction.